# Threads in C# [Question]

Tags: c#, .net

Thread1/2: do TotalThreads-- on their exit

```
int TotalThreads = 2;

void AsyncFunc() {
 // run thread for Func()
}

void Func() {
 // run Thread1 
 // run Thread2
 while(TotalThreads > 0) { /* do nothing */ }
 // some code
}
```

is that bad design?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out are N threads finished.

Comment: Are you trying to wait for all the threads to complete by polling TotalThreads? If so, this is not a good way to be doing it. But please clarify your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I want the simplest solution.

Comment: How are you runing the threads, as new Threads or on the ThreadPool using QueueUserWorkItem or using Delegate.BeginInvoke etc?

Comment: new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadedFunc))

Comment: Instead of /* do nothing */, you could try something like Thread.sleep(0); I believe it will make it more efficient, but somebody else will have to confirm this. Also, are integers in C# automatically atomic or locked? If not, decrementing them might not be thread-safe.

Comment: Why would you put `[Question]` in your title?  Was it not already obvious that you are posting a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating new threads using System.Threading.Thread, you can use Thread.Join on each thread instance. This will block the main thread until the running threads have completed.

Based on your comments, this example should match your requirement.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsyncFunc));
      Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsyncFunc));

      t1.Start();
      t2.Start();

      // Wait here for the 2 threads to complete
      t1.Join();
      t2.Join();

      Console.WriteLine("Done");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void AsyncFunc()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this implies you're decrementing `TotalThreads` inside each thread as it completes? You'd have to synchronize access to the variable otherwise you'll have a race-condition.

In general, there are better ways of doing things. The simplest is to explicitly join each thread at the end of your code, to wait for them to terminate:

```
thread1.Join()
thread2.Join()
```

If you want to do this for multiple threads, you could put them all into a `List`, and then `Join` them all inside a `foreach` loop.

If you just want to run a couple of `AsyncFunc`, an even nicer way is using the Parallel Extensions, available in .NET 4.0, or backported to 3.5 in the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) library:

```
Parallel.Invoke(AsyncFunc, AsyncFunc);
```

This will run two copies of the function in parallel, and return after they both complete.

Answer (score 1):

Using a "busy-wait" (that's what you are doing with your while loop) is never a good idea. 
Let each thread signal when it's finished via a delegate and decrement your totalthreads counter in that event handler (Don't forget to lock the counter during that operation).

When all threads are finished, call another function that will continue with whatever you want to do next.

Comment: OK but delegates are runned in the thread calling them. I want to close each thread, and continue my work on the main thread only. How to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) for lets-wait-for-threads-to-finish synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the [`Thread.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.